# azure service bus message reappear timeout

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

If I have a service bus brokered message receiver configured. and it fails for any reason. I call on it

```
 message.abandon();
```

however this means the message will be back again in the queue/subscription.

can i configure a timeout after which the same message is available in the queue for processing.

For example: if there is only one message in the queue. and it's failing, then it is not good to keep processing it every second or every minute. if i configure something, that can make sure, the failed/abandoned message only reappears after 30 mins . then it is useful.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you abandon a message, you cannot supply a "cool off" time. The message will be available right away. It won't be dead-lettered until `MaxDeliveryCount` attempts have been exhausted. Once all those processing attempts have been used up, the message will go to the dead-letter queue.

If you need to postpone message processing, there are several options.

**Deferring a message**

You could defer a message using `BrokeredMessage.DeferAsync()`. The message will go back to the queue for future processing and a `SequenceNumber` of the message will be returned. The caveat with this approach is the need to hold on to the `SequenceNumber` in order to retrieve the message later. If you happened to lose `SequenceNumber`, it is still possible to browse for deferred messages and retrieve those. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral).

**Scheduling a new future message**

Another option would be to clone an incoming failing message, schedule it for some time in future using `BrokeredMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUTC` and completing the original message. With this option, I'd recommend to send the new message scheduled in future to be dispatch using [send-via feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions), also known as [Transaction Processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-transactions), to leverage atomic operation of completing the incoming message and sending the outgoing one. This way the code will not produce "ghost" message if completion fails. More [information here](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus--canceling-scheduled-messages).

**Scheduling using client, not message**

Another option is to schedule using a client and not `BrokeredMessage` using `client.ScheduleMessageAsync(). It will return a`SequenceNumber` you need to hold on to, but using this API a message can be cancelled at any point in time w/o waiting for the schedule time to arrive or receiving the message. More [information here](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus--canceling-scheduled-messages).

Comment: thanks! can you provide link which explains send via feature? the link provided is also opening cancelling scheduled message page. :)

Comment: Added the link @MandarJogalekar

Comment: @SeanFeldman you deserve a gold medal for that BTTF reference in your blog post. Great answer btw!

Comment: Thank you, @Alex. A bit dated, but the concepts remain the same.